# CSRF token missing or incorrect in json data with post request using JavaScript, Django 2.0, Python 3.6

Tags: django, django-views, xmlhttprequest, python-requests, http-post

My JavaScript post request using `json` data:

```
function myAjax(type, url, data){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
     }
  };
  xhttp.open(type, url, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  //xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
  var br = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(br);
  type=="GET"?xhttp.send():xhttp.send(br);
}
data={
  csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{csrf_token}}",
  sss: 'sssssssss',
}
myAjax("POST","http://localhost:8008/testv/",data);
```

JavaScript console output:

```
{"csrfmiddlewaretoken":"WcQnuWdsGgxDlTf5r8VKypuXpVCms0ElSxzACMg9cRIkOQLGbb92EkoxEfLT2qzS","sss":"sssssssss"}

POST http://localhost:8008/testv/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

Django shell:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /testv/
```

I don't want to use `@csrf_exempt`.

Comment: Try adding this to your headers:
headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')
    }

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

Comment: @2Pacho Thanks man. I have solved it already.